# Xamarin.Forms: Share a gradient between two Views

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, gradient, custom-renderer

I have a custom frame that I have created in Xamarin.Forms that allows for a gradient background. I am trying to create a compound shape from two different Frames both with a gradient background, but I am wanting the gradient to be shared between the two. I have gotten the desired effect with using Skia.Sharp.Forms but I would like to know if there is a way to do this with just using Xamarin.Forms and custom renderers.

An example of what I am looking for:

[image]

An example of what I get when using custom 2 custom frames: (pay no attention to the slightly different shape)

[image]

**EDIT**

My idea is I want to encapsulate the two frames (or any controls for that matter) in a Custom grid that is given the gradient colors. Then in the custom renderer of the Grid it sets the backgrounds of the children controls to the gradient. This way the `LinearGradient` has the starting point (0,0) of the parent grid and isn't creating a new gradient for each child. Here's some code to explain what I mean, I just havent figured out the part where I set the children's backgrounds to the gradient yet, the `SetLayerPaint`( method doesnt seem to work..)

```
        protected override void DispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        _gradient = new Android.Graphics.LinearGradient(
            0, 0, Width, Height,
            new int[] { _startColor.ToAndroid(), _middleColor.ToAndroid(), _endColor.ToAndroid() },
            null,
            Android.Graphics.Shader.TileMode.Mirror);

        for(var i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++ )
        {
            var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint()
            {
                Dither = true
            };
            paint.SetShader(_gradient);
            var child = GetChildAt(i);
            child.SetLayerPaint(paint);
        }
        base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
    }
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Add a view at background (Parent for both view) and set the gradient to that parent view. The shape view must be transparent. Have you try that?

Comment: I have, the problem with that is if you see the picture I need the space around that top tab to be white. and the parent view would set all of the background to the gradient including the white space

Comment: Oh! jezz, I just overlooked that.

Comment: You can use `LinearGradient` to achieve it with two 2 custom frames it may be easy, the first frames's end color is the same as the set first color of the second frames'.

Comment: I think that would work best if I were using a vertical gradient, but since I am using a diagonal line gradient the frames still dont quite match doing it that way.

Comment: I mean that I use lineargradient  and set the  ` GradientColorOrientation="Vertical"` Here is running screenshot https://imgur.com/a/moMir0t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:
The custom renderer for the Grid

```
public class GradientGridRenderer_Android : ViewRenderer
{
    private Xamarin.Forms.Color _startColor;
    private Xamarin.Forms.Color _middleColor;
    private Xamarin.Forms.Color _endColor;

    LinearGradient _gradient;

    public GradientGridRenderer_Android(Context context)
        : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if(e.NewElement != null && e.NewElement is GradientGrid grid)
        {
            _startColor = grid.StartColor;
            _middleColor = grid.MiddleColor;
            _endColor = grid.EndColor;
        }
    }

    protected override void DispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
        _gradient = new LinearGradient(
                0, 0, Width, Height,
                new int[]
                {
                    _startColor.ToAndroid(),
                    _middleColor.ToAndroid(),
                    _endColor.ToAndroid(),
                },
                null,
                Shader.TileMode.Mirror);
        for (var i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var child = GetChildAt(i);
            if(child is FrameRenderer_Android gFrame)
            {
                gFrame.Gradient = _gradient;
                gFrame.Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the custom renderer for the Child, if needed you could abstract this out and make any number of custom renderer's that take a gradient, but for my purposes I just needed a Frame.

```
public class FrameRenderer_Android : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.FrameRenderer
    {
        public LinearGradient Gradient;

        public FrameRenderer_Android(Context context)
            : base(context) { }

        protected override void DispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            if(Control != null && Gradient != null)
            {
                var paint = new Android.Graphics.Paint()
                {
                    Dither = true,
                };
                paint.SetShader(Gradient);
                canvas.DrawPaint(paint);
            }
            base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
```

And here is the xaml

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <cntrl:GradientGrid RowSpacing="0"
                      Margin="0,20,0,0"
                   StartColor="{StaticResource GracePink}"
                   MiddleColor="{StaticResource GracePurple}"
                   EndColor="{StaticResource GraceDarkPurple}"
                            IsClippedToBounds="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="90*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <cntrl:CustomFrame Grid.Column="2"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               IsClippedToBounds="True"
                               CornerRadius="20,20,0,0">

            </cntrl:CustomFrame>
            <cntrl:CustomFrame Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               IsClippedToBounds="True"
                               CornerRadius="40,40,0,0">

            </cntrl:CustomFrame>
        </cntrl:GradientGrid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```